Need help in deciphering meaning of Asian Characters (Characters identified: 晴正之印)
Acquired a hand-carved figurine with symbols on it's base, and would appreciate if someone could  tell me what it says or means, if anything?


Take a clear picture and upload it.

If it says: 晴正之印 (I can't read these seals) then it just says:
晴正 qíngzhèng
之 zhī
印 yìn
晴正 qíngzhèng would be the name of the artist or company that made the statuette,  之 works like the, 印 means print or mark or stamp.
Altogether: The Seal of Qíngzhèng
晴 qíngzhèng : clear weather, skies
正 zhèng: just right
So maybe 晴正 qíngzhèng is "Clear Skies Company (or Group)", the manufacturer rather than an individual artist's name.
晴字用着取名寓指乐观、活泼、上进、美好之义。
Using 晴 qíng in a name implies optimism, liveliness, progressiveness and beauty.
晴，读作qng，
晴，read qng，
本义是指夜里雨止云散，
originally referred to night-time when the rain stopped, the clouds dispersed,
天上出现星星；
and the stars appeared;
后来泛指雨雪停止、无云或少云的天气，
later it was used as a general reference to when the rain or snow stopped, and there were few or no clouds,
白天有太阳，
(when) there was sunshine during the day,
夜里有星星、月亮。
(or) stars and moonlight at night.
